# After resetting iPhone, does Find My iPhone remain activated?

Tags: restore, iphone, find-my-iphone

Suppose the following scenario.

1. iPhone is disabled and the "Continue with iTunes" message is shown. The passcode has been forgotten.
2. iPhone restored via recovery mode using iTunes.
3. iPhone is restarted. Activation steps are followed.
4. Connected to Wi-Fi and SIM card install message is shown.

Is the Find My iPhone feature still ON in iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7, Apple introduced a new feature called Activation Lock.

Activation Lock prevents someone from stealing your phone because they can't restore it and use it without your Apple ID and password.

So yes, Find My iPhone is still on because activation lock is still on. Find my iPhone can only be turned off by going to **settings > iCloud > Find My iPhone**, then flipping the switch and entering your Apple ID password.

You should need your password to activate the iPhone.

Comment: And if someone dont restore it..just activate via new itune account.then?

Comment: @sangramparmar In order to use the phone after a restore, you HAVE TO enter the iCloud password of the original owner.